# Unable to print current ViewController Name using method swizzling

Tags: ios, swift

I want to print `ViewController` name, Instead of printing screen name in every `ViewController` is there any other possibilities to print `ViewController` name using `ViewController` extension? or any suggestions?.

**For Example**  If you are in login page it should print `LoginViewController` and if you moved to home screen it should print `HomeViewController` I have tried below code but it's not printing exact class name.

```
extension UIViewController {
@objc dynamic func _tracked_viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    print("ClassName@: "+String(describing: type(of: self)))
    _tracked_viewWillAppear(animated)
}

static func swizzle() {
    if self != UIViewController.self {
        return
    }
    let _: () = {
        let originalSelector =
            #selector(UIViewController.viewWillAppear(_:))
        let swizzledSelector =
            #selector(UIViewController._tracked_viewWillAppear(_:))
        let originalMethod =
            class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod =
            class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!);
    }()
}
```

And In `Appdelegate.swift` file

```
func application( _ application: UIApplication, 
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
            launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
            ) -> Bool {

               UIViewController.swizzle()

             return true
}
```

Output:-

```
ClassName@: UIInputWindowController
ClassName@: UISystemKeyboardDockController
ClassName@: UICompatibilityInputViewController
ClassName@: UICompatibilityInputViewController
ClassName@: UICompatibilityInputViewController
ClassName@: UICompatibilityInputViewController
ClassName@: UICompatibilityInputViewController
ClassName@: UISystemKeyboardDockController
```

But it is not printing name of `ViewController`.
Thanks.

Comment: `let class_name = "\(HomeViewController.classForCoder())"`

Comment: `let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
`

Comment: @AnuragSharma it should be "\(self.classForCoder())" not "\(HomeViewController.classForCoder())" because i written in UIViewController extension. Here i'm trying to print class name using method swizzling.

Comment: That's… quite overkill. If you achieve it please share.

Comment: @ManuMateos yes i achieved it you can try this in your project. The code which i have written above is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like

```
struct StringUtils {
    static func className(_ obj: AnyObject) -> String {
        return String(describing: type(of: obj))
    }
}
```

And then call it as follow

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(StringUtils.className(self))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `type(of: T)` method

```
print(type(of: self))
```

Playground example:

```
import UIKit

class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(type(of: self))
    }
}

let vc = SomeViewController()
vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

> **Output:** SomeViewController

Comment: Here we need to write  print(type(of: self)) in viewDidLoad of every class but i need a solution like print the Current visible VIewController name dynamically.

Comment: There are quite a few different ways you could do this. create a custom UIViewController that does this and have all of your others inherit from it. You could create a custom navigation controller which prints all of the classes that it sets/pushes

Answer (score 0):

You can write a UIViewController subclass yourself, override the viewDidAppear method, and use this code:

```swift
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("Shown viewcontroller " + String(describing: type(of: self)))
        // (do whatever)
    }
```

Then, inherit from this class from the rest of the classes.

Comment: Can we print the same with extension of UIVieController?

Comment: You can print `String(describing: type(of: self)` from wherever, not just a UIViewController. This subclassing and overriding is to ensure every screen prints the message.

An extension is more or less the same than adding a method to a class. You need to call that function from somewhere to run that code.

Comment: If you want, extend UIViewController and add that line of code to a new method, then you can call the method from any view controller.